# Generate numbered SVG pins for map

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a need to automatically generate 'path' formatted SVG icons for a map. Essentially I'm looping over a set of locations, and drawing them on a map. I'd like each 'pin' to be a numbered icon generated at run time, something like this.

[image]

The library I am using requires me to feed in the icons as an SVG, string, I guess? I'm not super familiar with SVG so the terminology is unfamiliar to me. But for example I have something like this.

[image]

Which ends up drawing icons looking like this.

[image]

So essentially what I am looking for is a javascript function that I can feed in an integer, and it spits out of the SVG path code for a small numbered icon. Any help, pointers, sample code, would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What does your data look like? Can you add some of it to the question? (and not as a picture)

Comment: Is the map part of the SVG as well or would it be separate map and icons in HTML?

Comment: The map is it's own thing. The framework I am using simply asks for a set of map markers, and it handles drawing the map, over which I do not have much control.

Answer (score 0):

The circle bit is easy enough, that’s just a bunch of arcs:

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}
svg {
  width: 110px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-5 -5 110 110" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M 100 50 A 50 50 0 0 1 50 100 A 50 50 0 0 1 0 50 A 50 50 0 0 1 50 0 A 50 50 0 0 1 100 50 Z" style="fill: rgb(255, 0, 0); stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255); stroke-width: 5px;"/>
</svg>
```

Rendering the numbers is the challenging part of this problem. If you are running on **Node.js** you can use the package [text-to-svg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/text-to-svg) to generate an SVG path from a string and a font file. If you want to do it in a browser, [@LeetCodes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1021340/leetcodes) says it can be done [using the outputs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60022127/2518285) from `npm run build`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Alas I am not using Node.js, I'm using a framework provided by Salesforce CRM to generate this map, so I'm a bit limited in what I can do, hence was hoping to do this front end with javascript, as the only back end language I have access to is Apex (their proprietary Java like langauge)

Comment: As I said, it should be possible to have Node.js build some files which you can then run on the front end. Review those links I sent. I haven't tried it myself, however. Another solution might be to ditch your idea of generating the markers at run time, and instead generate them ahead of time using an SVG editor like [Boxy SVG](https://boxy-svg.com/). You can then hard-wire the SVG code strings into a Javascript array in your code, so you can just pull them out at run time.

Comment: Ah I see, I'm sorry I misunderstood. I think pre generating is probably the way to go, seeing as I probably would never need more than 30 or so at a time. I'll take a look at those tools, thank you.